# how to simplify this program

Tags: matlab

i've done this programme but my lecturer want it to be more simple.. i tried to change the command but it goes wrong.. can please help me.. give some clue or whatever.. i really appreciate if u can help me.. this is the question and below is the command.. To determine the highest, lowest and the average value of two vectors depending on user own choice by mean of MATLAB Programming..

```
   close all
   clear all
   clc

     disp('Welcome to my program.');
     disp(' ');
     disp('instruction:');
     disp(' a ) Enter the number of column of a vector.');
     disp(' b ) Next, enter the element for vector A and vector B.');
     disp(' c ) Then, select your option of what do you want to find.');
     disp(' ');
     column = input (' Enter the number of column of a vector: ');
     disp(' ')
     disp(' Enter the element for vector A ');
      for count=1:column 
        disp(['A (',num2str(count), ')=']);
        A(count)=input(' ');
    end
   disp(' ')
   disp(' Enter the element for vector B');
    for count=1:column
        disp(['B(',num2str(count),')=']);
        B(count)=input(' ');
   end
    disp(' ')
    disp(['Vector A is [',num2str(A),')']);
    disp(['Vector B is [',num2str(B),')']);
    disp(' ')
    disp('What do you want to find?');
    disp(' ')
    disp('1-find the highest value');
    disp('2-find the lowest value');
    disp('3-find the average value');
    choose=input('Choose:');
   disp(' ')

    while choose >3
        disp('Sorry, please enter the right input!');
        choose=input('choose:');
    end

    disp('Your result:')
   disp(' ')
    fprintf('number of column:%2.0f\n',column);
    disp(['vector A:[',num2str(A),']']);
    disp(['vector B:[',num2str(B),']']);

    if choose ==1
        disp('choice: find the highest value');
    elseif choose==2
        disp('choice: find the lowest value');
    elseif choose==3
        disp('choice: find the average value');
    end
    switch choose
       case 1 
            A = max(A);
            B = max(B);
           result=max(A,B);
       case 2
            A = min (A);
            B = min (B);
           result=min(A,B);
       case 3
            A = mean (A);
            B = mean (B);
    end

    disp(['Vector A:',num2str(A)]);
    disp(['Vector B:',num2str(B)]);
    if choose==1
        disp(['the highest value: ',num2str(result),'']);
    else if choose==2
            disp(['the lowest value:',num2str(result),'']);
        end
    end
```

Comment: "i tried to change the command but it goes wrong" : What did you try and how did it go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a few changes:

1. Ask your professor what "simpler" looks like.
2. Modularize - put code in smaller methods that you call.
3. Less prompting of input.  I'd object to that stuff about min, max and mean.  Just put them all out for goodness' sake.
4. Visually the code is a bit of a mess.  I'd have smaller methods; keep the code clean.
5. Looping to prompt for input is one way; reading from a file would be another.  I'd give myself the option of where I got values from.  Keep that separate from the calculations.

Comment: what do you mean 'keep the code clean'?

Comment: I think all that display stuff is visual clutter.  Separate the computations from all the I/O and prompting.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this:

```
function out = mergevectors(x,y,method)
%MERGEVECTORS  Determine max, min, or mean value
%    MERGEVECTORS(X, Y, 'CHOICE') determines basic statistics between two
%    vectors.  X and Y are any identically sized vectors.  'METHOD' is one
%    of:  'max','min','mean'.
%
%Examples:
%    x = [1 2 3 4];
%    y = [4 3 2 1];
%    mergevectors(x, y,'max')
%    mergevectors(x, y,'min')
%    mergevectors(x, y,'mean')


%Error handling
error(nargchk(3,3,nargin));
if ~isequal(size(x), size(y))
    error('X and Y must be identically sized')
end
if ~ischar(method)
    error('Method must be one of ''max'', ''min'', ''mean''');
end

%Processing
switch lower(method)
    case 'max'
        out = max(x, y);
    case 'min'
        out = min(x, y);
    case 'mean'
        out = (x + y)/2;
    otherwise
        error('Method must be one of ''max'', ''min'', ''mean''');
end
```

---

A few self-indulgent comments:

- Please avoid statements such as: clear all;close all; clc;  I understand why so many people do it, but if I'm using your tool, there is a chance I have something in my workspace that I would like to keep.  This statement is not needed.  If you are worried about stray variables in your workspace, the `function` keyword works just fine.
- There is no need to guide the user though a longwinded method of typing in a vector.  the Matlab command window already comes with tools suitable to enter a vector.  (e.g. `[`  and `]`).
- In general, error messsages should be completely neutral in tone.  No "!"'s.  Any error is at least half the fault of the programmer who could not find a method of working with the input provided, or providing better documentation.
- In the solution provided, the initial comment block serves as documentation, and is available to the user via `help mergevectors`.  However once a user has become an expert user, the documentation is no longer needed, and does not intrude.
- Avoid interactive input such as `input` whenever you can.  (That is, always avoid interactive input.)  The whole point of writing a useful function is so that you (or someone else) can use it well after you have forgotten how it works, and you can use it to build better, more advanced functions.  You rarely want to slow this process down with constant requests for input.

  This point may not be obvious for this learning example, but if you are ever writing complex pieces of code (regardless of the language) this is a point to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Consider how MATLAB's built-in functions are constructed.  The user simply selects the case by passing an additional argument.  Instead of prompting the user via the display, there are a set of comments below the function call that the user can request by calling "help yourfunctionname"

So very crudely, you should write a function that looks something like this:

```
function f = yourfunction(A,B,i)
%A and B are input vectors
%i = 1 for max, i = 2 for min, i = 3 for mean

'the rest of your code'
```

Comment: It's more user-friendly if you rename `i` to `calc_type` and allow it to be a string in `min|max|mean`. Then use `strcmp()` to determine which calculation to use. (Note for the unwary: don't compare strings using the `==` operator - it doesn't work like you think.)

Comment: You see that guy's code?  Baby steps.